# Huawei Appgallery. How to my app be released in the mainland Chinese market?

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, appgallery, appgallery-connect

My app is already approved on Appgallery but may be Huawei is very strict approval in the mainland china market. they sent me a refusal mail to publish in china. I revised the app and app copyright information but wasn't approved while outside of China was released.
huawei has emailed me but quite complicated, i don't know how to provide the requirements they propose. How to my app be released in the mainland Chinese market ? sorry my english is bad. Thank you !

All email information is as follows:

> Dear developer,
>
> Thank you for contacting us!!
>
> Your app failed the review. The detailed description and modification
> suggestions are as follows:
>
> Detailed description: Your app failed the review due to lack of
> qualification documents for AV entertainment-music apps.
>
> Modification suggestion: The Computer Software Copyright Certificate
> or APP Electronic Copyright Certificate must be provided for the
> audio-visual entertainment-music category.
>
> For details about the copyright qualification review requirements, see
> https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/distribution/app/30215
>
> Your app did not provide the qualifications needed in Mainland China,
> the publishing in Mainland China and other countries or regions you
> have chosen to publish has been affected.
>
> For specific qualifications,
>
> Please refer to:   https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/30215
>
> [Description]: We found that there is no related privacy statement in
> your app. The publishing in Mainland China and other countries or
> regions you have chosen to publish has been affected until all the
> requirements above are met. For more information, please refer to the
> rule 7.1 of "AppGallery Review Guidelines":
> https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/distribution/app/50104
>
> [Suggestion]: Please provide related privacy statement in your app.

Comment: hi@NguyenDuc,I think the e-mail made it very clear,Can you elaborate on what you don't understand?Maybe you can [Submit a ticket online](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/support/feedback/#/) or provide your app ID and app name for us to query.

Comment: I submitted a ticket online. I received the same response.  But I don't have to how do I get my application accepted in mainland china ? Please show Youtube video on how to publish app in mainland china market ?

Comment: hi NguyenDuc,i updated my answer,pls kindly refer that

Answer (score 0):

The first question is that lack copyright qualification.

You need to submit the copyright qualification according to your own app classification and the regulations in this document:

[Submission of Copyright and Publication Approval Number](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/distribution/app/30215)

Copyright Qualification Submission Path:

You may upload it directly in console-App service-AppGallery Connect-my apps-select your app-version information-copyright information--upload  certificates -resubmit your app for review.

Second question: It's also written in the email,

> [Suggestion]: Please provide related privacy statement in your app.

You need to add the privacy statement to your app. Generally, you can add the privacy statement to your app login home page or my module.

Comment: I have uploaded copyright information and uploaded but still is not approved and received email above. 
Actually I don't know how I can publish my app in the mainland china market. Can you make a sample of the video on how to provide copyright information and post it on youtube ?

Comment: hi@NguyenDuc,could you pls provide your appid for us to query?

Comment: app id: 104201477

Comment: Looks like you have ask a new question [How to provide The Computer Software Copyright Certificate in China](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67216256/how-to-provide-the-computer-software-copyright-certificate-in-china),Let's continue discuss on that question

Answer (score -1):

Looks like this question was answered by Shirley and moved to:

[How to provide The Computer Software Copyright Certificate in China](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67216256/how-to-provide-the-computer-software-copyright-certificate-in-china)

[image]

**My supplemental answer:**

Shirley has answered most of your questions. To supplement her answer and respond to your question - "How to i have The Computer Software Copyright Certificate to provide huawei appgallery (in China Mainland)?", it is correct that you will need to apply for Software Copyright Certificate, however you must have a China Mainland entity such as China identity card or China registered corporation to apply. If you are not a China citizen or don't have a company in China, there is no way to apply for this certificate; in that case most non-China developers use proxy companies like AppInChina to publish on their behalf.

Certain app categories such as "Tool" are exempted from Computer Software Copyright Certificate requirement so you are eligible to publish in China Mainland.

If your app is not published in China Mainland, please review app review remark in your email. The common issues are:

- privacy notice not accessible from within China
- user cannot review privacy statement
- user account registration/login problem
- SMS code verification issue
- app content unavailable (developer should test app using a China VPN
  and see if it perform normally)

Comment: False information " however you must have a China Mainland entity [...] to apply. If you are not a China citizen or don't have a company in China, there is no way to apply for this certificate;"
According to this link https://forums.developer.huawei.com/forumPortal/en/topic/0203480680985250017
1. Can I get a Software Copyright Certificate if I’m not a Chinese company? 
Yes, the copyright owner can be a foreign company or legal person, but you must submit the legal proof certified by the local Chinese consulate or notarized by the local notary office.

Comment: @adrianvintu Confirmed with Huawei team recently, the information that you referred to is no longer available. Although it seems doable, I don’t know of any overseas developer (who doesn’t have a China Mainland entity) that has successfully obtained China Software Copyright Certificate and used it to publish in China AppGallery. If you know of any successful cases, I would love to hear from you. The information that I have provided is still a valid solution and I have helped some overseas developers to publish their apps this way.