# How to provide The Computer Software Copyright Certificate in China

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, appgallery

I recently published the application to Huawei Appgallery. Outside China approved. But in mainland China it was rejected. they asked me to provide The Computer Software Copyright Certificate.
How to i have The Computer Software Copyright Certificate to provide huawei appgallery?

All email information Huawei Appgallery sent is as follows:

> Dear developer,
>
> Thank you for contacting us!!
>
> Your app failed the review. The detailed description and modification suggestions are as follows:
>
> Detailed description: Your app failed the review due to lack of qualification documents for AV entertainment-music apps.
>
> Modification suggestion: The Computer Software Copyright Certificate or APP Electronic Copyright Certificate must be provided for the audio-visual entertainment-music category.
>
> For details about the copyright qualification review requirements, see https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/distribution/app/30215
>
> Your app did not provide the qualifications needed in Mainland China, the publishing in Mainland China and other countries or regions you have chosen to publish has been affected.
>
> For specific qualifications,
>
> Please refer to: https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/30215
>
> [Description]: We found that there is no related privacy statement in your app. The publishing in Mainland China and other countries or regions you have chosen to publish has been affected until all the requirements above are met. For more information, please refer to the rule 7.1 of "AppGallery Review Guidelines": https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/distribution/app/50104
>
> [Suggestion]: Please provide related privacy statement in your app.

Answer (score 4):

In China, Computer software copyright (SCC) refers to the exclusive rights enjoyed by software developers in accordance with the copyright laws and is used to prove and protect the copyright of your mobile app. On the one hand, it’s a necessary certificate for some categories of apps, because it can prove the ownership of the app to the Chinese app stores. On the other hand, it can prevent your code from plagiarizing or pirating and is an important proof of app infringement.

**Where to apply for Software Copyright Certificate?**

The State Copyright Administration is in charge of the registration of the certificate in China, you can apply for it on the website of China Protection Center of China (http://www.ccopyright.com.cn/). And the applicant may register the computer software copyright by yourself self or entrust an agency to register the copyright.

**List the detailed process for obtaining Software Copyright Certificate**

For individual registering, the process can be divided into five phases: Fill in the application form → submit the application documents → accept the application → examination → to obtain the registration certificate; If you have an agent to help you, just provide the materials directly to the institution, and they will handle the application for you.

**What materials are required to register a Software Copyright Certificate?**

The application documents for software copyright registration shall include:

Ø  Application form for software copyright registration;

Ø  Software identification materials;

Ø  Identity certificate of the applicant;

Ø  Identity certificate of the contact person;

---

Once you got that,You may upload it directly in console-App service-AppGallery Connect-my apps-select your app-version information-copyright information--upload  certificates -resubmit your app for review.

[image]

For more detail about the Computer software copyright,  please send an email to gochina@huawei.com.

And you can also refer this [link](https://forums.developer.huawei.com/forumPortal/en/topic/0203480680985250017) to get The Complete Guide to Software Copyright Certificates in China.

Comment: What should I do if I want to register for Software Copyright Certificate ? Why is China's policy for developers so complicated ? Terrible complexity.

Comment: Sorry@NguyenDuc,just like i answered above,On the one hand, it’s a necessary certificate for some categories of apps, because it can prove the ownership of the app to the Chinese app stores. On the other hand, it can prevent your code from plagiarizing or pirating and is an important proof of app infringement.

Comment: What should I do if I want to register for Software Copyright Certificate ?
http://www.ccopyright.com/en/index.php?optionid=1005

Comment: Hi Dear,Just confirmed with the team that you have selected an incorrect application category last time. For tool applications, you do not need to upload the Software Copyright Certificate. And your new application is correct. So just wait for the review is fine. :D

Comment: Does my application approved for release in mainland china ?

Comment: Not yet. It's still being reviewed. It shouldn't be long. :D

Comment: Is it still true that tools don't need SCC's? Because on [link](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/app/30215) it states:

Qualification Requirements:
(1) Value-added Telecom Business License -> where do I get this? I'm from Germany?

Additional Requirements:
(1) Disclaimer
(2) Computer Software Copyright Certificate or App Electronic Copyright Certificate

Comment: @shirley sorry, forgot to mention you...

Comment: hi@Malmatth, yes, just confirmed with the review team, Tool applications except Accelerators,Browsers,Network disks and cloud storage do not require Computer Software Copyright Certificate.

Comment: @shirley so if my app is TOOL application (just a basic notes widget), I do not require any copyright info? So how to release app to mainland chinese market, if it does not let me submit app without copyright? How did you solve it? Thanks a lot for help

Comment: @qkx So far, there's no change: *Tool applications except Accelerators,Browsers,Network disks and cloud storage do not require Computer Software Copyright Certificate.* That means your app(a basic notes widget) can be release without copyright certificate, and If it fails the review, you can provide your appID then i will contact the review team to confirm. :D

Comment: @shirley thanks a lot for your help! So I asked at Huawei support. This is what they replied: https://ibb.co/VV11XDr I am confused now...I have only 2 apps - both are tools - calendar widget and notes widget, if that helps.

Comment: hi@qkx , just checked with the review team again, and the reply was Tool applications except Accelerators,Browsers,Network disks and cloud storage do not require Computer Software Copyright Certificate, and if you cannot submit after clicking Upload, check whether the [Disclaimer](https://communityfile-drcn.op.hicloud.com/FileServer/getFile/cmtyManage/011/111/111/0000000000011111111.20210622154551.42244137852752504598259217756790:50520929072804:2800:35FBEE65DCAA6D277CD54FF13DE58C906227CF2EFFBF6D41837B8CFA05C7C7E9.zip?needInitFileName=true) is uploaded.

Comment: @qpk, I made a small [note](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qyPpC.png), note that  disclaimer is required for all apps. If you have any queries, please feel free to contact us back. :D

Comment: Oh thank you so much for your help!!! I am big fan of Huawei, since Google needs a good competition. I will try to upload my app with disclaimer, and if they reject it, I will text you again, thanks a lot again

Comment: yes, you can use the template I provided. The disclaimer needs to be printed out and signed and uploaded. A signature or seal is required at "seal required".

Comment: @shirley Here I am again. My application has been rejected due to the following things missing: "(1) Computer Software Copyright Certificate or APP Electronic Copyright Certificate (2) ICP archive screenshots plus handwritten signature (3) Individual developer commitment letter". I sent them your small note from above but they replied that individual developers always need to provide those things even for tools. ([this is their reply](https://ibb.co/dtywqbx)) Is that true? My application is a tool (not an Accelerator, Browser, Network disks or cloud storage).

Comment: hi@Malmatth could you pls leave your appID for us to check?

Comment: sure @shirley, thank you for the fast reply! It's 105470829

Comment: hi@Malmatth, sorry, confirm with the review team that the current review rules have been updated just like the screenshots you provided. All app relesed to the mainland of China must comply with this requirement, and the rules will be updated in real time according to the regulatory requirements, the actual review results prevail.

Comment: Thanks @shirley, this was sobering but helpful. Maybe this should be updated on [this](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/distribution/app/30215) website as well. This was the link provided by the review team and it still states that for tools no certificate is needed. However, thank you so much for your help!

Comment: For my small tool application it is defenitely not worth to register a  Computer Software Copyright Certificate. I would need to entrust an agency for that, as the site is only available in Chinese and one even needs a chinese phone number to register. This is pretty frustrating since I adapted my app to HMS only to reach the chinese market and now it is not worth it / possible anymore.

Comment: @Malmatth Sorry for the inconvenience, the document you mentioned has been reported to the relevant team for modification as soon as possible.

Comment: It's not possible to release apps on mainland china for us indie developer. It should be clearly stated that china blocks foreign software developers so we dont waste time on this.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to release apps on mainland china for indie developer. It should be clearly stated that china blocks foreign software developers so we don't waste time on this.

Comment: Seems like it is the case. It is close to impossible to have an Paid App in App gallery as Individual Developers. :(