# Publish app Huawei Appgallery in the China

Tags: publishing, huawei-developers, appgallery

To publish app to China we need to provide The Computer Software Copyright Certificate. How to have The Computer Software Copyright Certificate to provide Huawei AppGallery?

The official [site](https://www.ccopyright.com.cn/) doesn't work and returns `400 Bad Request` when trying to access the [Copyright Section](https://register.ccopyright.com.cn/publicInquiry.html?type=softList)

[image]

Also the [English version of the site](https://www.ccopyright.com/en/) doesn't work and returning this ->

[image]

Also for some unknown reasons when the site looks like working sometimes, i can't register since don't have any Chinese phone number.

Does anyone face the same issue or ***is there any other way*** to get that kind of Certificate elsewhere to be able to publish the app to China Mainland?

What is the best guideline to follow to easily be certified and be able to operate with China App Markets ?

Comment: [Similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67222788/13329100). The applicant may register the computer software copyright by yourself self or entrust an agency to register the copyright. You can learn more at the Copyright Center website: https://www.ccopyright.com.cn/index.php?optionid=1033 (The web page is in Chinese, you can try to translate the page).

Comment: @shirley, there are 2 other issues which i have mentioned different from the above question. Firstly the site is giving me errors and secondly i wonder if there is another way to get certified

Comment: @shirley, also for some reasons when the site looks like working i can't register since don't have any Chinese phone number... This is why i am asking if there is another way